# ruby random string comparison method

Tags: ruby, string, methods, random, compare

I am trying to run different code using randomly generated types.  Creating random types (`self.type`) works. However, I want to use these types: `Early`, `Late` or `On Time` to conditionally run code based on the string `self.type` returns.  Thanks in advance!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'forgery'

class Forgery::MyRecord< Forgery

  TYPES= Forgery::Extend([
    { :type => "Early" },
    { :type => "Late" },
    { :type => "On Time" }
  ])

  def self.type
    TYPES.random[:type]
  end

  a=self.type
  puts a
```

This works up to this line of code. It randomly returns `Early`, `Late` or `On Time`.
But, how can I use `type` in my method? Thanks!

```
  def self.deadline
    if self.type=="Early"
      puts "early"
      #removed other code
    elsif if self.type=="Late"
      puts "late"
      #removed other code
    elsif if self.type=="On Time"
      puts "on time"
      #removed other code
    else 
      puts "Missing"
    end   
  end

  b = Forgery::MyRecord.deadline
  puts b 
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is: Every time you call `type` it returns a random value. Therefore you check against different values in each if condition.

Change your code to this:

```
def self.deadline
  case type
  when "Early"
    puts "early"
    # removed other code
  when "Late"
    puts "late"
    #removed other code
  when "On Time"
    puts "on time"
    #removed other code
  else 
    puts "Missing"
  end   
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I think this is working, but I don't know how to test. I made two minor changes: 1) replaced case "Late" with when "Late and 2) replaced case "On Time" with when "On Time".

Comment: To test a method returning a random value I would probably first test that the method itself returns any of the possible values. For other methods that are using that random value I would stub the return value of that method with a fixed value.